# ¿Que esta mal en esta sintaxis?

Tags: mysql, trigger, sintaxis

tengo un error de sintaxis en este trigger que no logro identificar. Alguien me podria ayudar a delucidar que esta mal?

El trigger es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
    /*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
    TRIGGER `AGENDA_UPD_AFT` AFTER UPDATE ON `agenda` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF (NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda <> OLD.cotizacion_2da_moneda) THEN
          DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda   decimal(9,2) default '0.00';
      SET Cotizacion2daMoneda    = NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda;
      UPDATE articulos_x_proveedor SET precio_neto = precio_neto_2da_moneda * Cotizacion2daMoneda;
    END IF;
    END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

El mensaje de error que recibo al querer ejecutarlo es:

> Error Code : 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda   decimal(9,2) default
> '0.00';     SET Cotizacion2daMo' at line 6 (0 ms taken)

Comment: Prueba colocando `DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda  DECIMAL (9,2) DEFAULT 0;`

Comment: Sigo recibien el error :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la documentación:

> [13.6.3 DECLARE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/declare.html)
>
> ...
>
> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound
> statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.
>
> ...

Una traducción libre sería algo como:

> ...
>
> `DECLARE` solo se permite dentro de una declaración compuesta `BEGIN ... END` y debe estar al comienzo, antes de cualquier otra declaración.
>
> ...

Un par de opciones para solventar el problema:

- Opción 1

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `AGENDA_UPD_AFT` AFTER UPDATE ON `agenda` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda decimal(9,2) default '0.00';

  IF (NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda <> OLD.cotizacion_2da_moneda) THEN
    -- DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda decimal(9,2) default '0.00';
    SET Cotizacion2daMoneda = NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda;
    UPDATE articulos_x_proveedor SET precio_neto = precio_neto_2da_moneda * Cotizacion2daMoneda;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

- Opción 2

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
/*!50017 DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' */
TRIGGER `AGENDA_UPD_AFT` AFTER UPDATE ON `agenda` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda <> OLD.cotizacion_2da_moneda) THEN
    BEGIN
      DECLARE Cotizacion2daMoneda decimal(9,2) default '0.00';
      SET Cotizacion2daMoneda = NEW.cotizacion_2da_moneda;
      UPDATE articulos_x_proveedor SET precio_neto = precio_neto_2da_moneda * Cotizacion2daMoneda;
    END;
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```